# Constant accessible from all modules

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to have constant that is accessible from my other modules.
I tried something like below, but there's exception.
How should I modify my code to make it work?

```
angular.module('starter', ['starter.Authentication'])
.constant('baseUrl', 'http://myUrl/api/');

angular.module('starter.Authentication', ['baseUrl'])

.factory('AuthenticationService', 
['baseUrl',
function (baseUrl) {
    var service = {};
    return service;
};

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.Authentication due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module baseUrl due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'baseUrl' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
angular.module('starter.Authentication', ['baseUrl'])
```

To:

```
angular.module('starter.Authentication', ['starter'])
```

This is because `starter` is a module that holds the `baseUrl` constant.

Comment: Thanks, I created then additional module for constants and now it works.